# How to configure syslogd name/identifier?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog

I'm forwarding all syslog events to papertrailapp.com, and they are identified as sent by `localhost`. It's not convenient, since I have a few servers and all of them are `localhost`-s. How can I configure syslog on every machine to have their own unique names?

Comment: You mean that you have servers without hostnames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that by setting the hostnames for these computers.

(r)Syslogd does not have a option to set a hostname to transmit/log-